# Tracker or Recoll?

Tags: linux, pdf, indexing, full-text-search

I want to use Tracker to index my PDF collection.
Before I choose a tool I searched around for available Linux indexers and one of my references is this wiki: [link](http://www.wikinfo.org/index.php/Comparison_of_desktop_search_software#Feature_comparison), where is stated that Tracker does not support full text search while tracker website says it does: [link](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/features.html)

I want full text search so I thought to ask here for opinion and answer which tool is best in my scenario (just PDF FTS indexer) on Debian where performance is also considered and "live" indexing is not required

Comment: Just one thing I will mention in case it's helpful: it seems a lot easier to index individual documents with recoll than tracker (as opposed to directories). But Tracker has a nicer output format so neither is ideal for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you already found your tool, anyway seems that http://www.recoll.org/ does the job. PDF is a supported format (be careful installing the required dependencies on debian) and after the indexing task, you can use it without the need of daemons wasting your resources.

Reference at this article for a deep, and very comprehensive, comparison of tools.
http://richfriedeman.com/2010/02/28/choosing-an-open-source-desktop-search-tool-part-3/

Comment: The second link is outdated and I can't find die changed link.